# How to really deal with indexing in Redis and correctly implement indexes

Tags: indexing, redis, stackexchange.redis

I am moving some "live" data structures from MySQL to REDIS. Using StackExchange C# Redis Client, I'm writing (due to some very project-specific restrictions) my own microORM code to store and retrieve object class entities from a Redis Database.

I am pushing c# object as hash keys in Redis.

My general question is about indexing on fields other than the "primary key".

Ok, I've read all the theory of sets and sorted sets, and how to add and remove members from sets, and so on.

I've added some code to correctly create set keys which contain entities hash keys, so that I can lookup those objects by simple indexes or sorted indexes.

However I cannot find or figure out a good strategy for solving the following problems:

**1. Index maintenance on expiration**

I'd like to add expiration to some object (hash) keys, so that old entities get purged automatically by Redis. However I cannot find a reilable way to update/purge relevant indexes besides running periodically a background task that scans index set keys for expired members and removes them (notification is not good for me)

**2. Index updating when some object fields change**

In some cases I need to update only a small fraction of hash key values, not the whole entity. If the fields being updated are part of one or more index set keys, I cannot figure out the best way to properly update the set keys.

For example, let's say I need to store a "Session" entity whose primary key is its ID (simple numerical integer), and I need to add an index on the "Node" string field (Node being the reference to the server currently serving the session):

```
class Session {
    [RedisKey]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string RemoteIP { get; set; }
    [RedisSimpleIndex]
    public string Node { get; set; } 
}
```

`RedisKey` and `RedisSimpleIndex` are attributes I use to extract via reflection which fields are used as primary key and which are used for indexing.

Let's suppose I have an instance of `Session` like this:
`{ ID = 2, RemoteIP = "1.2.3.4", Node = "Server10" }`

My routines are creating the following keys in Redis:

Hash key: `"obj:Session:2"`

Hash values: `"ID" = "1", "RemoteIP" = "1.2.3.4", "Node" = "Server10"`

Set key `"idx:Session:Node:Server10"`

Set members: `"obj:Session:2"`

which is fine for looking up all sessions on Server10.
However, if the very same session needs to be moved to a different server (e.g. `Server8`)and I want to update only the `Node` field in the Hash set, how can I update indexes too?

The only way I found so far is to SCAN all index keys with pattern `idx:Session:Node:*` and remove from them any member `obj:Session:2`, then create/update the index key for the new node (`idx:Session:Node:Server8`).

Moreover the SCAN command is not available in IDatabase or ITransaction interfaces, and in a HA Clustered environment things get worse since I need to determine which Redis server is holding relevant keys to make this procedure work.

Is there a better way to build/represent simple indexes in Redis? Is my approach wrong?

Comment: It seems like you should consider RediSearch, https://www.nuget.org/packages/NRediSearch/

Comment: Notice, the RediSearch client is part of the stackexchange client RediSearch.io

Comment: Fine, I gave up doing indexing on my own and switched to RediSearch, although I have several issues here too, but I'll post a separate question, thanks @GuyKorland

Comment: Sounds like you prefer to solve problems in a 'DB' oriented way, with queries over fields with indexes for efficiency. But that is not really what redis is. Redis is mainly a key value store, with a few extra data structures. Or 'not the abstraction you were looking for'. You might be better off using an actual database SQL or noSQL if you really want that feature set. But if not, then something like redisearch is a nice tool to bridge the gap...

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to add expiration to some object (hash) keys, so that old entities get purged automatically by Redis. However I cannot find a reilable way to update/purge relevant indexes besides running periodically a background task that scans index set keys for expired members and removes them (notification is not good for me)

1. You cannot expire individual KV pairs within a hash. This is was discussed in [#167](https://github.com/redis/redis/issues/167#issuecomment-2559040). There don't appear plans to change this.
2. I *think*, you should be able to use [keyspace notifications](https://redis.io/topics/notifications) to subscribe to *expire* events. You would have to have some worker that subscribes for them and updates all relevant indices accordingly. However, you might get some inconsistent data. For example, your worker might crash and leave the stale indices behind. Also the indices wouldn't be updated instantaneously, so you'd end up with a bit of stale data regardless.
3. Probably not the best idea, but you could also hack in some custom indexing logic into [`expire.c`](https://github.com/redis/redis/blob/unstable/src/expire.c). The code seems fairly straightforward. The C module API by contrast doesn't appear to provide any way to hook into the eviction logic.

Another option is to not rely on Redis when it comes to handling expiration logic. So... you would still have a background job, but it would actually issue corresponding `DEL` commands for expired KV-pairs. This would also allow you to keep the index 100% up to date via transactions.

> In some cases I need to update only a small fraction of hash key values, not the whole entity. If the fields being updated are part of one or more index set keys, I cannot figure out the best way to properly update the set keys.

I'm not sure which Redis client you're using, but I found the following pattern to be quite useful in the past:

1. You have some form of "Updater" class for each hash. It has setters for all relevant fields that could be updated (`setFirstName`, `setLastName` etc.).
2. When you set a field, you mark *that particular field* as "dirty" (e.g. via a separate boolean).
3. When you call "save", you update indices for fields that were marked as dirty.

> The only way I found so far is to SCAN all index keys with pattern idx:Session:Node:* and remove from them any member obj:Session:2, then create/update the index key for the new node (idx:Session:Node:Server8).

This is cumbersome, but seems like the way to go. Sadly I don't think there is a better solution for this. You might want to consider maintaining a separate set with keys of index KV-pairs that would have to be updated though, as that way you'd avoid going over a bunch of keys that aren't relevant.

You might also want to check out [an article](https://www.memurai.com/blog/model-hash-attributes-using-secondary-indexes-in-redis-and-memurai) about how to maintain those indices. As you already alluded to, there are basically two options: real-time using `MULTI` transactions or using batch jobs. Once you get into the territory of using key expiration, you are more or less forced to use the batch approach.